# Background image not occupying the entire screen when run on a tablet

Tags: android-studio, user-interface, gridview, layout, scrollview

The background image

```
android:background="@drawable/jhyti"
```

is not occupying the entire screen when the application is installed on a tablet.
I'm using a scroll view and my layout parameters are

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:background="@drawable/jhyti"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
```

how can I make my background image to occupy the entire screen?

Answer (score 0):

change scaletype in xml file and also the width and height in relative layout

```
<LinearLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:scaleType="fitXY"
   android:background="@drawable/jhyti"
   android:orientation="vertical">
 <RelativeLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

or add the below code in java file and then try

```
 ImageView simpleImageView= 
(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.simpleImageView);
  simpleImageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
```